# Dog identifier in blockchain

Tags: transactions, qrcode

I would like to print qr-code with transaction that contains my home address to print it for my dog's necklace. If dog will get lost everyone can scan it and get the address.
How can I prepare the transaction?

Comment: Why don't you just print the address as a QR-Code? What's the benefit of it being on the blockchain, when you want people to scan it from your dog's necklace?

Comment: Because I want my dog to be the bitcoin user ;)

Comment: Is this to put a reward for finding your dog in the case that is is lost? If so, you'd need to put a private key, not the public address. The public address is what you pay TO. What good does having an address on the blockchain associated with your dog do?

Comment: Guys, it is just example to show how to prepare the transaction with custom message :P

Comment: Your example doesn't work and only makes the question confusing. There are no custom messages in transactions.

Comment: @Jannes: http://wlangiewicz.com/blog/2014/10/24/how-to-put-custom-messages-into-bitcoin-blockchain-op-return/

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki That's not something that you can put in a QR code. A transaction doesn't go into a QR code at all. I guess you could put an URL in the QR code that points to a blockchain explorer with a transaction ID. Still makes no sense though. Just make a website with your home address on it and make a QR code with the URL to that. Which still doesn't make sense. Why don't you create a vCard QR code? http://snapmyinfo.com/vcard/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Janina Lowisz of Bitnation's BlockchainID project [became the first "World Citizen on the Blockchain"](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/world_passport/) by making a sort of blockchain passport:

[image: Janina Lowisz's blockchain passport]

Something similar could be done for identifying pets.

For instructions on how she did it, see:
https://github.com/MrChrisJ/World-Citizenship